# Twitter and Facebook for Socialize

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, buzztouch, socialize-sdk

I'm trying to get Twitter and Facebook to work on Socialize for my iOS app. I've followed the steps on Socialize's website up until the "Linking to existing credentials" area (Twitter: http://socialize.github.io/socialize-sdk-ios/twitter.html, Facebook: http://socialize.github.io/socialize-sdk-ios/facebook.html). When I run the app, it successfully builds but Facebook and Twitter still do not show up as options for sharing. I have a feeling there's some small part I'm missing but can't figure it out. Does anyone know if maybe there is something that Socialize does not mention in the guide that may need to be done or some other possible answer?

Thanks, 
David

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the following in the app delegate, or another place, follow the documentation:

> ```
> [SZFacebookUtils setAppId:@"YOUR FB APP ID"];
> [SZTwitterUtils setConsumerKey:@"YOUR_TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY" consumerSecret:@"YOUR_TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET"];
> ```

http://socialize.github.io/socialize-sdk-ios/facebook.html

http://socialize.github.io/socialize-sdk-ios/twitter.html